# Slicing a tuple of vectors into a tuple of std::optional(s)

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

I'm having trouble slicing a `tuple`.

I want to output a `tuple` with `std::optional`, so that if the `vector`s are of an uneven length, the tuple is padded with empty `std::optional` objects.

An example of my implementation is below, but I'm running into a roadblock, which is commented in the if-statements

```
template <typename... Types>
auto sliceTuple(std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...> &data, int index)
{

    std::tuple<std::optional<Types>...> output;

    std::apply(
        [&output, index](auto &vector)
        {
            if (index < vector.size())
            {
                //Problem here: How would I write vector[index] to the tuple? 
            }
            else
            {
                //Problem here: How would I write an empty std::optional to the tuple?
            }
        },
        data)

    return (output);
}
```

If `std::apply` had a compile-time index, it would be trivial, (I could just use `std::get<i>(output);` ) but as far as I know, it does not. Is there a way to implement this "slice tuple of vectors" function, and if so, how would I do so?

An example of what I want to do:

Starting with a tuple of 3 vectors:

```
<[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]>

should become 

<1, 3, 6> when index = 0
<2, 4, 7> when index = 1
<empty std::optional, 5, 8> when index = 2
```

Comment: What `index` does? What should happen when each vector has different size?

Comment: @MarekR The function should return a std::tuple that corresponds to std::get<0>(data)[index], std::get<1>(data)[index], etc. When each vector has a different size, an std::optional is used to pad the tuple.

Comment: I don't quite get the question.  You say you want to go from a tuple of vector to a vector of tuples but in your code you are going from a tuple of vectors to a tuple of optionals

Comment: @NathanOliver Rephrased the question, the end goal is to slice to a vector of tuples but this function only slices from a tuple of vectors to a tuple of optionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
template <typename... Types>
auto sliceTuple(std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>& data, size_t index)
{
    return std::apply([index](const auto&... vs) { 
        return std::make_tuple([index](const auto& v) { 
            if (index < std::size(v))
            {
                return std::make_optional(v[index]);
            }
            return std::optional<Types>{};
        }(vs)...);
    }, data);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T68YPxcsY

Here is version which is spitted into two parts:

- apply tuple on lambda which constructs tuple of optionals
- take index based optional from a range

```cpp
template <typename R>
auto optional_from_range(const R& r, size_t index) -> std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(r[index])>>
{
    if (index < std::size(r)) {
        return r[index];
    }
    return {};
}

template <typename... Types>
auto sliceTuple(std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>& data, size_t index)
{
    return std::apply([index](const auto&... vs) { 
        return std::make_tuple(optional_from_range(vs, index)...);
    }, data);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z7xrbr4d3

this should be easier to understand.

Comment: Magic! I don't understand it, but that's part of the learning process! I guess I have some more reading to do.

Comment: Will try improve it to make it more readable.

Comment: It could just be me not having enough experience. I'm used to the programming mindset, but I'm still pretty early on in my C++ journey.

Comment: This should be more clear now.  I used TDD approach of tree steps: failing test, write code to pass test (here was my first version), refactor (this was last version).

Comment: @Kevin • *It could just be me not having enough experience.*  Meta-programming is hard.  C++'s (in my opinion) atrocious meta-programming syntax makes meta-programming even moreso harder than it already is to begin with (which is already hard enough).  My usual suggestion is to get it to work in non-template way, then abstract to meta-programming.  But this problem is probably not amenable to that approach, so thanks to Merek R and 康桓瑋 for solutions.

Comment: @eljay This began as a relatively simple project, and I decided that I wanted to make it use templates as a learning exercise. Months of on and off work later, and I'm still working out a lot of the issues I've had. Thankfully learning that you can use Fold expressions in ```std::apply``` solves a lot of my problems. I do wish we had a compile time for loop, though.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `std::apply` and the fold-expression:

```
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <typename... Types>
auto sliceTuple(std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>& data, int index) {
  return std::apply([index](auto&... vecs) {
    return std::tuple(
      (index < vecs.size() ? std::optional(vecs[index]) : 
                             std::nullopt)...);
  }, data);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/76T3TWKcE)